# Need help writing remove() for global query scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my scope, the `apply()` method works wonderfully.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class JobStatusScope implements ScopeInterface
{

    /**
     * Apply scope on the query.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder
            ->where('active', true)
            ->whereHas('user', function($q) {
                $q->where('account_type', 'company')
                    ->whereNested(function($r) {
                      $r->where('stripe_active', true)
                        ->orWhereNotNull('subscription_ends_at')
                        ->where('subscription_ends_at', '>', Carbon::now())
                        ->orWhereNotNull('trial_ends_at')
                        ->where('trial_ends_at', '>', Carbon::today());
                });
            });
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope from the query.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        //dd($query->wheres);

        $columns = ['stripe_active', 'subscription_ends_at', 'active', 'trial_ends_at'];

        foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where) {
            if (in_array($where['column'], $columns)) {
                unset($query->wheres[$key]);

                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What I tried in my `remove()` method didn't work.

I have this in a trait file, and attached to my Model

```php
use App\Cable\Traits\Scopes\JobStatusScope;

trait JobStatusTrait {

    public static function bootJobStatusTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new JobStatusScope);
    }

    /**
     * Get the query builder without the scope applied.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public static function withAll()
    {
        return with(new static)->newQueryWithoutScope(new JobStatusScope);
    }
}
```

When I try to run `MyModel::withAll()->get()` it should return all records without the `apply()` constraints but it does not.

When I `dd($query->wheres)` in the `remove()` method and call the `->withAll()` I get this

```php
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "type" => "Null"
    "column" => "jobs.deleted_at"
    "boolean" => "and"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "type" => "Basic"
    "column" => "active"
    "operator" => "="
    "value" => true
    "boolean" => "and"
  ]
  2 => array:5 [▼
    "type" => "Basic"
    "column" => Expression {#478 ▼
      #value: "(select count(*) from `users` where `jobs`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `account_type` = ? and (`stripe_active` = ? or `subscription_ends_at` is not null and `subscription_ends_at` > ? or `trial_ends_at` is not null and `trial_ends_at` > ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)"
    }
    "operator" => ">="
    "value" => Expression {#476 ▶}
    "boolean" => "and"
  ]
]
```

I can't seem to figure this out. Most of Laravel is quite easy to figure out, and it is so "eloquent", but this escapes me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `whereHas()` restriction works by use a subquery to get the count of the related records.

As you can see from your `dd()` output, the `column` for your target `where` clause is not just a plain string (like 'active'), but is an Expression object that contains the subquery.

You'll need to write some logic to determine if this Expression is the one that matches the subquery generated by the `whereHas()`, so you can remove it if it is.

A simple example would be something like the following (n.b. not syntax checked or tested):

```php
public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $query = $builder->getQuery();

    // your plain column names
    $columns = ['active'];

    // columns present in the user relationship subquery
    $userColumns = ['stripe_active', 'subscription_ends_at', 'trial_ends_at'];

    foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where) {
        // first check if the column is really an Expression
        // if it is not an expression, do the normal check on strings
        if ($where['column'] instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression) {
            // get the sql value of the Expression
            $sql = $where['column']->getValue();

            // see if all the user columns are in the sql statement
            $count = 0;
            foreach($userColumns as $name) {
                // increment count if the user column was found
                $count += (stripos($sql, $name) !== false) ? 1 : 0;
            }

            // if all the user columns were found, assume this is the where and remove it
            if ($count == count($userColumns)) {
                unset($query->wheres[$key]);

                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        } elseif (in_array($where['column'], $columns)) {
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);

            $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to come up with something a little more strict than just checking if all the column names are in the SQL, but this should get you started.

Comment: I came up with a similar solution, I will award you this as it is what my line of thinking was. Thanks! - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/need-help-writing-remove-for-global-query-scope/replies/73068